# Is there a way on how to post data from a native mobile application then save the data through the Drupal Website?

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-webform, hook-menu

Is there a way to post data from a native mobile application written in HTML, CSS and JQuery then save the data through the Drupal Website (particularly on the Webform module)?

Let's say, in my native mobile application, I have this set of code:

[mymobile/json-inquiry.js]

```js
var inquiry = {'inq_name' : fullname, 'inq_email' : emailadd, 'inq_number': contactnum, 'inq_message' : msg };
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://local.mywebsite.com/inq/',
          type : 'post',
          data :  inquiry,
          success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
          }
        });
      });
    },
```

```js
  $items['inq'] = array(
    'title' => 'Test1',
    'description' => 'Getting the Reservation data from the mobile app to here',
    'page callback' => array('test_inquiry1'),
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
```

Then I would like to input the following data into the tables of Webforms, particularly on the `webform_submitted_data`. I'm having difficulty solving that kind of problem namely because there are so many relationships tied on the Webform Module. Could someone help me on this one?

Answer (score 0):

The [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) and [Webform Service](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_service) or [RESTful Web Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/restws) modules can help you